# Unexpected battery discharge on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery-life

I charged my smartphone yesterday to full 100%. When I woke up today, I saw that battery was 40%. Android OS has used 90% of the battery. My Android version is 4.0.3. What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: I had that two times, some service going havoc. A reboot always solved that. Before getting the wrong idea: No, it happens rarely. And my phone is switched on 24/7, I only boot it when really needed ;)